# message.guild returns null in discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im making a discord bot that sends a user that sends a message to every member in the server. It worked a while ago but without chaning anything it suddenly stopped working. Not to sound egotistical but i doubt its anything with my code and more just something i forgot to setup but in the case its me, i've sent the code below

```
client.on("message", message => {
    const { guild } = message

    console.log(guild)
```

i've tried to get the guild at different spots in the process but it doesn't seem to work. I've looked at the docs but that didn't help a lot. They also just use `message.guild`. I tried just printing the `message` object and it returns

```
Message {
  channel: DMChannel {
    type: 'dm',
    deleted: false,
    id: '795038485052522546',
    recipient: User {
      id: '358317103834726401',
      system: null,
      locale: null,
      flags: [UserFlags],
      username: 'T3CH',
      bot: false,
      discriminator: '6969',
      avatar: 'a_578305126220c42a2de15defb32ad2b6',
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessageChannelID: null
    },
    lastMessageID: '797538660227481650',
    lastPinTimestamp: null,
    messages: MessageManager {
      cacheType: [class LimitedCollection extends Collection],
      cache: [LimitedCollection [Map]],
      channel: [Circular]
    },
    _typing: Map {}
  },
  deleted: false,
  id: '797538660227481650',
  type: 'DEFAULT',
  system: false,
  content: 'There was an error finding the guild',
  author: ClientUser {
    id: '764065338592591873',
    system: null,
    locale: null,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    username: 'Greg Michaelson',
    bot: true,
    discriminator: '6184',
    avatar: '4fc90843924c172c60c126c0284e9561',
    lastMessageID: '797538660227481650',
    lastMessageChannelID: '795038485052522546',
    verified: true,
    mfaEnabled: true,
    _typing: Map {}
  },
  pinned: false,
  nonce: null,
  embeds: [],
  attachments: Collection [Map] {},
  createdTimestamp: 1610218434150,
  editedTimestamp: 0,
  reactions: ReactionManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection [Map] {},
    message: [Circular]
  },
  mentions: MessageMentions {
    everyone: false,
    users: Collection [Map] {},
    roles: Collection [Map] {},
    _members: null,
    _channels: null,
    crosspostedChannels: Collection [Map] {}
  },
  webhookID: null,
  application: null,
  activity: null,
  _edits: [],
  flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  reference: null
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no guild object when a message is received via a direct message

Comment: omfg i just realised i have been dming the bot instead of using the command on a server thank you so much xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else wondering why the error occurs it is because JanuZz_dk was direct messaging the bot, this means that there is no `<Guild>` object inside of the `<Message>` response.

You can check the type of channel that the message has come from programmatically like this:

```js
if(<Channel>.type == 'dm') {
    // Message has come from a direct message
}

if(<Channel>.type == 'text') {
    // Message has come from a channel in a guild
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Pentium1080T** : There is no guild object when a message is received via a direct message

ik im dumb but thank you